# CPE v2.3 - Naming conventions in Microsoft OS products

Tags: windows, operating-system, naming-conventions

I have some questions about naming conventions in Microsoft products (operating systems only) with CPE:

1. In what CPE v2.3 field should I assign "R2" (Release)? For example: "Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2"
2. In what CPE v2.3 field should I assign the OS edition? in 'edition' or 'sw_edition'? For example: "Microsoft Windows 7 Home Premium"
3. In general, what are the differences between 'edition' and 'sw_edition'?

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not certain. CPE uses both `<cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_server_2008:-:r2:x64:*:*:*:*:*"/>` and `<cpe-23:cpe23-item name="cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows_server_2008:r2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"/>`.
2. `edition` is deprecated now.
3. `edition`:

> The edition attribute is considered deprecated in this specification, and it SHOULD be assigned the
>   logical value ANY except where required for backward compatibility with version 2.2 of the CPE
>   specification. This attribute is referred to as the “legacy edition” attribute.
>   If this attribute is used, values for this attribute SHOULD capture edition-related terms applied by the
>   vendor to the product. Values for this attribute SHOULD be selected from an attribute-specific validvalues
>   list, which MAY be defined by other specifications that utilize this specification. Any character
>   string meeting the requirements for WFNs (cf. 5.3.2) MAY be specified as the value of the attribute.

`sw_edition`:

> Values for this attribute SHOULD characterize how the product is tailored to a particular market or class
>   of end users. Values for this attribute SHOULD be selected from an attribute-specific valid-values list,
>   which MAY be defined by other specifications that utilize this specification. Any character string meeting
>   the requirements for WFNs (cf. 5.3.2) MAY be specified as the value of the attribute.

[Common Platform Enumeration:Naming Specification](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistir/ir7695/NISTIR-7695-CPE-Naming.pdf)